# Workstation does not unlock when connected remotely to server

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I am working on servers using mstsc, and everything works until I lock my workstation.

When I try to log back in to my account, I am told my password or user id is invalid.

The only way that I can log back in is to shut down via the power button and restart.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and what the solution is.

It only affects my machine and not others, despite them all being built the same.

The station has been rebuilt several times but the problem persists.

The workstation is using Windows 7 32 bit and we use Windows Server 2003 and 2008.

Comment: I was wondering if it could be something strange happening to your keyboard layout, e.g. the remote server has a US keyboard layout and yours is UK. Have you tried typing your password into the username field to see if the right characters appear? Don't hit return or your password may be stored in an event log in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Sahmeepee has a good point. It is possible your keyboard layout changes and therefor chars are changing.

My first question would be, how do you lock the workstation, and secondly, are you sure you have locked your workstation, and not the connection remotely? If you have locked the remote session and you use a different username/password there, that can be the reason it won't accept it.

I've seen a case where, when locked, the locked account was not mine, but an administrator account. Can you verify that it is indeed locked by your user?

Also, if you have the password of a local administrator account, you can always log your user off by logging in using a local username/password combination. By default the local user: Administrator is disabled, so you don't have to try that unless you have enabled this user.

Don't forget to specify your computername as domain if you want to specify a local username and your pc is in a domain. For example, if your pc is named: Mypc, you would write mypc\user (or user@mypc) as username.